# Aplicação android de task flow?

Tags: android, path, task

É possível criar uma aplicação que faça um "path" pro usuário?

Por exemplo, ao rodar a aplicação ela chama um intent pro usuário setar o horário e a aplicação "espera" os eventos de usuário pra poder ir pra uma outra task, e assim seguindo um caminho definido pelo aplicativo.

Se sim, existe algum nome pra isso pra que eu possa procurar mais sobre?

Comment: Parece que está falando de um wizard. Seria então um application wizard ou algo desse tipo. Seria isso?

Comment: Mais ou menos, algo parecido com um "Guide" que tem em alguns apps, mas utilizando serviços do próprio Android. O meu foco principal é na automação, rodar um app em background que faça caminhos pré-definidos pro usuário. To começando a achar que não seja possível hehe

Answer (score 0):

O android vem cada vez mais limitando ação do seu app ao escopo da sua sandbox. Isso aumenta a segurança para o usuário.

No caso de esperar setar as horas, acredito não ser possível, mas existem alguns broadcasts que o sistema te envia, como por exemplo mudança para modo avião, status de bateria. Pode conferir alguns aqui: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#constants_2

Esse foi o melhor tutorial que encontrei explicando como ouvir esses broadcasts 
https://code.tutsplus.com/pt/tutorials/android-from-scratch-understanding-android-broadcasts--cms-27026